# Asymptotic series : why doesn't Mathematica compute it in power of $1/x$?

Tags: series-expansion

Consider the following :

```
Series[Cos[Pi/2*Sqrt[n/x]] - Cos[Pi/2*Sqrt[(n + 1)/x]], {x, Infinity, 
  2}]
```

I expect mathematica to find me the $1/x$ perturbative expansion.
Analytically the first order is if I didn't do any mistake: $\frac{\pi^2}{8} \frac{1}{x}$

But mathematica answers me:

```
Cos[1/2 \[Pi] Sqrt[n/x]+O[1/x]^5]-Cos[1/2 \[Pi] Sqrt[(1+n)/x]+O[1/x]^6]
```

He doesn't really answer my question. How can I formulate my question to mathematica more properly ?

Comment: I get `\[Pi]^2/(8 x)+(-\[Pi]^4-2 n \[Pi]^4)/(384 x^2)+O[1/x]^3` with version 12.0.

Comment: @Xminer I have the same result if I put 1 as last parameter

Comment: @StarBucK ah,I misunderstand the question.sorry x(

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what I have version 11.3

Comment: In version 10.0 I get the same result as @b.gates.you.know.what. Could it be a bug in version 11.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in version 11.3.

```
Series[Cos[Pi/2*Sqrt[n/x]] - Cos[Pi/2*Sqrt[(n + 1)/x]], {x, Infinity,2}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

> $$\frac{\pi ^2}{8 x}+\frac{-\frac{\pi ^4 n}{192}-\frac{\pi ^4}{384}}{x^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}\right) $$

Comment: In MMA 11.0.1 it works without any assumptions!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: What was asked, that was answered. A partial workaround in 11.3 was proposed by me.

Comment: @user64494 yes this extra options makes mathematica indeed compute the series. Thanks !

Comment: @user64494 My comment indicates that the question is answered without any additional assumptions with MMA 11.0.1. And this point wasn't answered!